# Startup project 'xxx' targets framework '.NETStandard'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do Entity Framework Core migration for this project in github - https://github.com/johnph/simple-transaction#WebApi-Endpoints

but hit the above as shown below. I have also set the same project which I do the EF migration as 'startup project'. I tried to search on this error but no avail yet.

[image]

I have removed the existing project reference dll, recompiled and re-add the reference. I have also re-install Entity Framework Core and some other Nuget packages. At the end, I can clean and rebuild the whole solution without error.

The only thing I could not get it work is the EF code-first migration which create the database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just set your Transaction.WebApi as a startup project and in package manager console select Transaction.Framework for run add-migration 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. After I run `Add migration`, another error says `No DbContext was found in assembly 'Transaction.Framework'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.`

Comment: By the way, do you know where is the connection string? I can't see any at appsettings.json. Manually add it ourselves?

Comment: you must go there: \simple-transaction\src\Services\Transaction and open appsettings.json and finally add your connection string